# Incrementing variables in ASP.net on every button click

Tags: asp.net, datetime, postback

I want to increment date in every click ASP.NET.
But Every time the page posts back, it is essentially starting over from scratch - anything initialized to 0. 
I need to persist a value across postbacks but I don't how to do that. I would appreciate for any help.
Here is what I'am trying to do:

```
int myNumber = 0;
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
  lblDate.Text = DateTime.Now.StartOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Monday).AddDays(myNumber).ToShortDateString();
    myNumber++;
 }
```

Update: 
My finaly goal is to get next weeks first day with next button and Previous week, I mean I want to forword and backword...

```
public int NextCount
 {
    get { return ViewState["Count"] != null ? (int)ViewState["Count"] : 7; }
    set { ViewState["Count"] = value; }
  }



protected void btnNext_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            lblsum.Text = DateTime.Now.StartOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Monday).AddDays(NextCount).ToShortDateString();
            NextCount = NextCount+7;
        }

protected void btnPrevious_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblsum.Text = DateTime.Now.StartOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Monday).AddDays(NextCount).ToShortDateString();
            NextCount = NextCount - 7;
        }
```

But When I click Prev button .. there is delay with one click after two or three Click then reaction coming the same with next button when you click from prev to next. Maybe I have to store it in session?

Comment: Look for session, viewstate, static variable, http cache, db storage, file storage - depends on your needs :)

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar I just want to use it show next dates as a calendar. When I click I want to show next week's dates and next Click shows next of next week dates.. and so on ... I think myNumber should start with 6 or 7 but then I have to store it maybe in a seesion. So please help me how to do.. ;) Thank you in advance

Comment: @JonasWillander Please have a look below a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated your code below by using `ViewState` to handle this. Other easiest option would be storing the same in `Session`, `Cache` or `Cookie`.

> While storing a value in `ViewState`, it will create a `hidden` field
>   in the page and store the value to maintain it across the postback.

```
public int NextCount
{
    get { return ViewState["NextCount"] != null ? (int)ViewState["NextCount"] : 0; }
    set { ViewState["NextCount"] = value; }
}

protected void btnNext_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NextCount = NextCount+7;
        lblsum.Text = DateTime.Now.StartOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Monday).AddDays(NextCount).ToShortDateString();

    }

protected void btnPrevious_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NextCount = NextCount - 7;
            lblsum.Text = DateTime.Now.StartOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Monday).AddDays(NextCount).ToShortDateString();

        }
```

Comment: I have updated my question with some problems and I would appricate if you just check it.

Comment: @JonasWillander I have updated the answer above by moving the increment/decrement up. Please give a try.